# Is it possible to build free open hardware desktop PC?

Tags: hardware

I am in need of a desktop PC made only of Free and Open hardware components.

If I could be sure that such a thing is possible, I'd even be willing to build it myself; however, I can find no guides on Google on how to determine if this motherboard is open, or if that adapter released its firmware source.

I'm particularly interested in hardware that does not impede my ability to install my own firmware. Open hardware schematics are not necessarily a requirement.

How would you go about accomplishing this task?

Comment: Your definition of "Free and Open Hardware components" is components that have both (1) open hardware schematics and (2) free software drivers, correct?

Comment: @apsillers: Hmm...When you put it that way, I guess it would be "*hardware that does not impede my ability to install my own firmware*". I'm not sure if open hardware schematics are a necessary part of that.

Comment: Well if you're not sure then this question isn't sufficiently well defined...

Comment: @NoobSaibot Your question has already got one close vote from someone for being unclear, so I've edited your definition of 'free and open' into your question. Feel free to edit again (or rollback) if I've misinterpreted your position. And, welcome to Open Source.SE.

Comment: @curiousdannii And why exactly can an answer not address that? That shouldn't warrant an "unclear what you're asking vote."

Comment: @Ziz it's one thing to not know every legal implication, but this is a recommendation question! People would give two completely different answers depending on whether the licensing of the hardware needs to be considered or not.

Comment: I think it's an interesting question. Although not entirely clear, I believe it's clear enough to be answerable. Possible one of those questions where a good answer would point to the question OP would ask if they knew what to ask, but they don't, so they ask the question they asked. ++

Comment: @RubberDuck Well phrased! :)

Comment: it is possible but very complicated to get a 100% opensource modern machine

Answer (score 6):

I suggest taking a look at [EOMA68 computer cards](https://www.crowdsupply.com/eoma68/micro-desktop). They're expected to receive [RYF](http://www.fsf.org/resources/hw/endorsement/respects-your-freedom) certification, and you can order a desktop housing kit to go with yours.

Comment: Important precision, this is an ARM architecture...

Answer (score 3):

I've just discovered the [FSF Guide on Free Hardware](http://www.fsf.org/resources/hw). It appears to provide just enough information to make some informed decisions on hardware.

Comment: This is in no way a suitable answer for this site. Without the link, your answer is a comment. Don't forget, you can always quote content from another site and include it in your answer.

Comment: The information in that link says its hardware that supports GNU/Linux. It makes no mention about the openness of the hardware itself. Could be a good answer, but needs flushed out a bit.

Comment: This should be token as a recommandation nothing more... a complete hardware review is always required